# Angular: Toggling the active class on only the currently clicked button?

Tags: javascript, angular, class, conditional-statements

I'm trying to figure out how can I toggle the `active` class on **only the clicked button**:

This is my current code...

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isActive }" (click)="isActive = !isActive" type="button">Premier bouton</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isActive }" (click)="isActive = !isActive" type="button">Second bouton</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isActive }" (click)="isActive = !isActive" type="button">Troisième bouton</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isActive }" (click)="isActive = !isActive" type="button">Quatrième bouton</button>
</div>
```

...and this is the result:

[image]

I **DO NOT USE** `*ngFor` or `ng-repeat` principle. I know I need to **isolate** each button. How can I do that?

Adding `this.` to `isActive` doesn't work: `this.isActive`.

Comment: Make each button its own component with its own state? Store the index of each active button instead of just whether or not *any* button is active? Store an array of Booleans for each button's state?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Active button states in Angular + Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461181/active-button-states-in-angular-bootstrap)

Comment: @Stephan This duplicate question isn't the correct answer because the dev is using `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @Jonathan it is a duplicate question. The only difference in the solution is instead of using the index of the button to get the handle in the class change, you would use the id of the element, or pass it in on the event.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple, just use [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

**Component.html**:

```
<div class="btn-group" (click)="onButtonGroupClick($event)">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Premier bouton</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Second bouton</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Troisième bouton</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Quatrième bouton</button>
</div>
```

**Component.ts/.js**:

```
  onButtonGroupClick($event){
    let clickedElement = $event.target || $event.srcElement;

    if( clickedElement.nodeName === "BUTTON" ) {

      let isCertainButtonAlreadyActive = clickedElement.parentElement.querySelector(".active");
      // if a Button already has Class: .active
      if( isCertainButtonAlreadyActive ) {
        isCertainButtonAlreadyActive.classList.remove("active");
      }

      clickedElement.className += " active";
    }

  }
```

Live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/EE4dOMgpY8QA2qZXjMiW?p=preview

Comment: I accept this answer which is the most adecuate to fix my problem even if I'd like to see an "Angular way", much simplier one, implemented in the future in the framework. Thanks.

Comment: You can check my latest answer to find a more "Angular way" to proceed.

Answer (score 7):

I would just use a unique string for each button. For example:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" [class.active]="isActive('btn1')" (click)="setActive('btn1')" type="button">Premier bouton</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" [class.active]="isActive('btn2')" (click)="setActive('btn2')" type="button">Second bouton</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" [class.active]="isActive('btn3')" (click)="setActive('btn3')" type="button">Troisième bouton</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" [class.active]="isActive('btn4')" (click)="setActive('btn4')" type="button">Quatrième bouton</button>
</div>
```

Your `setActive` and `Isactive` functions would look something like this:

```
this.setActive = function (buttonName){
  this.activeButton = buttonName;
}
this.isActive = function (buttonName){
  return this.activeButton === buttonName;
}
```

So each button will pass its name, which is just some unique string. That string will be saved as a variable and will be used to determine if the active class should be applied.

Also you will notice you can toggle individual classes by binding to the class name. Like I did above for the active class, it can be bound with [class.active].

Answer (score 1):

What you do using [ngClass] is good but the problem is with your (click) event. The expression *isActive = !isActive* gives the error, when you click on the same button twice.

So, you can use different set of methods on each click event of the buttons.

In your **.ts** file, write as below

```
isValue: number = 0;  // This is a class property. By initializing with a value, you can set the default button highlighted

toggle1() { this.isValue = 1; }
toggle2() { this.isValue = 2; }
toggle3() { this.isValue = 3; }
toggle4() { this.isValue = 4; }
```

And in your html file, change as follows,

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isValue == 1 }" (click)="toggle1()" type="button">Premier bouton</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isValue == 2 }" (click)="toggle2()" type="button">Second bouton</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isValue == 3 }" (click)="toggle3()" type="button">Troisième bouton</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isValue == 4 }" (click)="toggle4()" type="button">Quatrième bouton</button>
```

Here, I have change only the (click) events and the [ngClass] .

Answer (score 1):

Instead a huge amount of toggleMethods you could use one with different number

.html

```
<div class="disease-wrapper">
          <div class="diease-tag" [ngClass]="{'active': isBtnActive === 1}" (click)="toggleBtn(1)">Heart Attack</div>
          <div class="diease-tag" [ngClass]="{'active': isBtnActive === 2}" (click)="toggleBtn(2)">Stroke</div>
          <div class="diease-tag" [ngClass]="{'active': isBtnActive === 3}" (click)="toggleBtn(3)">Cancer</div>
          <div class="diease-tag" [ngClass]="{'active': isBtnActive === 4}" (click)="toggleBtn(4)">Torn Acl</div>
          <div class="diease-tag" [ngClass]="{'active': isBtnActive === 5}" (click)="toggleBtn(5)">Broken Leg</div>
          <div class="diease-tag" [ngClass]="{'active': isBtnActive === 6}" (click)="toggleBtn(6)">Pneumonia</div>
          <div class="diease-tag" [ngClass]="{'active': isBtnActive === 7}" (click)="toggleBtn(7)">Torn Rotator cuff</div>
        </div>
```

.ts

```
  public isBtnActive: number = 1;
  toggleBtn(id: number) {
    this.isBtnActive = id
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using as below

```
clickedButton(event){console.log(event)
    let temp= event.srcElement.parentNode;
    for(let i = 0; i < temp.childNodes.length; i++){
      if(temp.childNodes[i].nodeName === 'BUTTON'){
      if(temp.childNodes[i].classList.contains('active')){
        temp.childNodes[i].classList.remove('active');
      }  }
    }
    event.srcElement.classList.add('active')

  }

<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary"   (click)="clickedButton($event)" type="button">Premier bouton</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary"   (click)="clickedButton($event)" type="button">Second bouton</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary"   (click)="clickedButton($event)" type="button">Troisième bouton</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary"   (click)="clickedButton($event)" type="button">Quatrième bouton</button>
</div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hj6Kjo56ukDJlumRl7By?p=preview)**

Comment: but it dosent toggle

Comment: you're not unsetting the state on the other buttons

Comment: Please update the whole answer @ once i feel anyways u are great at angular

Comment: @Aravind I agree with your solution but isn't there any "Angular way" to achieve that without using vanilla JS?

Comment: @Jonathan this is the way without using `ngFor`. lemme know if you find some thing new

Comment: @Aravind You should use `event.target` instead of `event.srcElement` which is used only with older versions of Internet Explorer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement

Answer (score 0):

you also can do it:

in your **.ts** file

```
isValue: number = 0;

toggle(num) { this.isValue = num; }
```

and in your html file change as follow

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isValue == 1 }" (click)="toggle(1)" type="button">Premier bouton</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isValue == 2 }" (click)="toggle(2)" type="button">Premier bouton</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isValue == 3 }" (click)="toggle(3)" type="button">Premier bouton</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isValue == 4 }" (click)="toggle(4)" type="button">Premier bouton</button>
```

and in your css file change as follows:

```
.active { background-color: gray; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for a more 'Angular Way' to proceed, here is another way, using **Service** coupled with **RxJs**. The idea is to have a `MenuService` which will store the active button reference as `Subject`. Your buttons will be able to subscribe to that `Subject`, receiving the new button reference when it changes. Testing that value in your button template will allow you to apply or not the active class.

This example can be elaborated with richer functions, but for explanation purposes, I will keep it as simple as it should be to answer the OP question.

First, create a new `Interface` (or `Class`, as you prefer) to define your button model. In this case, I will call it `MenuItem`. *In this example, MenuItem.ts is stored here `/src/app/_models/`*

**MenuItem.ts**

```
export interface MenuItem {
   label: string;
   routerLink: string;
}
```

Then, create the `MenuService` service. Here, you will need to declare a `BehaviourSubject` to store the reference of the clicked button. Using this method, you will be able to call `.next()` each time a new button is clicked and becomes the active one.

**menu.service.ts**

```
import { MenuItem } from 'src/app/_models/MenuItem'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MenuService {
    $activeButton: BehaviorSubject<MenuItem> = new BehaviorSubject<MenuItem>({} as MenuItem);

    constructor() {}
}
```

Next, create a component that will use a `MenuItem` as `Input()` property. Don't forget to inject `MenuService`. Therefore, you will be able to subscribe to the current active button stored in the service.

**menu.button.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu-button',
    templateUrl: './menu-button.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./menu-button.component.scss']
})
    
export class MenuButton implements OnInit {
    @Input() menuItem: MenuItem = {} as MenuItem;
    isActive: boolean = false;

    constructor(private menuService: MenuService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.menuService.$activeButton.subscribe((activeButton) => this.isActive = this.menuItem === activeButton);
    }

    setActive() {
       this.menuService.$activeButton.next(this.menuItem);
    }

}
```

You are now able to test the `isActive` property of your button and apply, or not, the desired class to it.  Don't forget to capture the `click` event and update the `$activeButton` value by calling `next()` and passing the new `menuItem` value using the `setActive()` method written above.

**menu.button.component.html**

```
<button [routerLink]="this.menuItem.routerLink" [ngClass]="{ active: this.isActive }" (click)="this.setActive()">{{ this.menuItem.label }}</button>
```